# Excel VBA setting Formula of range makes functions lowercase

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make VBA set a range of cells to a very simple formula:

```
Worksheets(newESheetName).Range("C3:C" & numItems + 2).Formula = "=LIGNE(C3)-2"
```

Forgive the french translation of the LINE function...

When I run the code, the result in each row (eg. 3) is:

```
=ligne(c3)-2
```

where the formula has become lowercase. Excel doesn't understand lowercase functions, so my column is full of `#NAME`?. I've tried explicitly putting `UCASE` around the string, but it still ends up lowercase. Thoroughly confused!

Comment: What happens if you put "=LIGNE(C3)-2" into the cells without using vba?  Excel does fine with lowercase functions (I tested putting "=sum(1,2,3)" into a cell and it worked perfectly fine, however, I was unable to find the "LINE/LIGNE" function you are referring to.

Comment: Also, as written, your formula has a circular reference....you are trying to put a formula using the value of cell C3 into cell C3.  Even if the function you describe exists, you would get a circular reference error.

Comment: @OpiesDad circular reference will not have place in this situation. `LIGNE` function, which is `ROW` in English, doesn't depend on cell value.

Comment: @EganWolf And a great point.  Incorrectly assumed that there were possible foreign language versions of Excel and that the OP had translated to Excel speak.  Those were pretty foolish in hindsight.

Comment: Can't test as my system is English - but `Evaluate()` would probably work quite well here.

Comment: Thanks for help all! The problem was France's fault ;). `ROW` worked - though why vba made my string lowercase I'll never understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, use English name of your function. In this case it's `ROW`.